# Unable to create modal dialog box

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

To put my problem succintly,

I am following the instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wb9s9ah.aspx

yet when i try to compile, it gives me the following error:

```
2>Link:
2>     Creating library C:\Users\Alvin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Emergence     
v1.3\Debug\EmergenceHandlers.lib and object C:\Users\Alvin\Documents\Visual Studio    
2010\Projects\Emergence v1.3\Debug\EmergenceHandlers.exp
2>EmergenceDoc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual    
__thiscall CFindDlg::~CFindDlg(void)" (??1CFindDlg@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function    
"public: void __thiscall CEmergenceDoc::OnEditFind(void)" (?   
OnEditFind@CEmergenceDoc@@QAEXXZ)
2>EmergenceDoc.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall    
CFindDlg::CFindDlg(class CWnd *)" (??0CFindDlg@@QAE@PAVCWnd@@@Z) referenced in function    
"public: void __thiscall CEmergenceDoc::OnEditFind(void)" (?  
OnEditFind@CEmergenceDoc@@QAEXXZ)
2>C:\Users\Alvin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Emergence    
v1.3\Debug\EmergenceHandlers.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

EDIT:

My code is as follows:

FindDlg.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Emergence.h"
#include "FindDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "resource.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CFindDlg, CDialog)

CFindDlg::CFindDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CDialog(CFindDlg::IDD, pParent)
{

}

CFindDlg::~CFindDlg()
{
}

void CFindDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CFindDlg, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

FindDlg.h

```
#pragma once

class CFindDlg : public CDialog
{
DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CFindDlg)

public:
CFindDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
virtual ~CFindDlg();


enum { IDD = IDD_FIND };

protected:
virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

Code inside CEmergenceDoc:

```
void CEmergenceDoc::OnEditFind()
{
    CFindDlg test;
}
```

Comment: You have declared a constructor and a destructor for `CFindDlg` class, but haven't actually implemented them.

Comment: Hi Igor. Thank you for the reply. How might I do this? Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Can you show the code inside the function: CEmergenceDoc::OnEditFind(void)

Comment: What is Emergence? A Dll or an Application? Seems that your compiler is missing entry point to your methods. Please check working directory too and lib locations.

Comment: Emergence is the name of the application. I don't think it has anything to do with my directories, as before i added the dialog it was all working perfectly...

Comment: Furthermore, all the code except for CFindDlg test; was generated by Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, that's pretty weird. You may try to delete all output folders, intellisense db and ipch directory. Then try a clean/rebuild solution. If this isn't working, delete the class you've added and all references to it. Then try it again.